# Hartl's Rails Tutorial (Chapter 8) - How to get home.html.erb to show the user profile when user is Signed In?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

First question on SO :)

At the end of the chapter 8, with the help of perm. cookie, different items could be displayed depending on whether the user is signed in or not.  I would like to make a minor modification to the book-suggested home.html.erb so that if the user is SIGNED IN, clicking on "Home" or the "Sample App" logo will no longer show the default blue sign in and welcome screen, but rather the user's profile.  In other words:

```
<% if !signed_in? %>
# if user is NOT signed in
# show the welcome and blue sign in buttons
<% else %>
# if user is signed in
# Render show.html.erb (i.e. the user profile) in app/views/users <-- this is where I am stuck on
```

Basically, the gist of my question is, how do I tell Rails to render another page in the home.html.erb environment?  This would be more analogous to Facebook or twitter, where if you are signed in, clicking on the logo would take you back to your profile page instead of a sign up page.

Much thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In the book session create action is

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

You must change `redirect_to` .check http://api.rubyonrails.org/..for usage of redirect_to.

Comment: Thanks.  Not quite what I'm looking for - I have exactly this in my user.controller.rb as well.  Currently, I am looking to modify the home.html VIEW so depending on the state of the user sign in, it would show different things.  I am able to get it to display a siple string rather than the normal grey hero-box and h1 text if the user is signed in, but now I want it to show the entire user profile.

Comment: You will use if signed_in? method ... first part will show the part with signed_in user .. second else part will show the other things. redirect_to @user shows you the page of signed_in user. if you say redirect_to about_path you can view the about.html.erb